# Batch: echo some text and read the rest of the line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I've got

```
echo sometext
set /p s=
```

but it will output the following:

```
sometext
*will read this line*
```

and I want it to be in the same line like this:

```
sometext *will read the rest of the line*
```

but HOW?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
SET /P s="sometext "
```

Will print `sometext` and place the prompt right after the text.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the input variable and put the double quotes on the right place:

```
SET "s="
SET /P "s=sometext> "
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Produces a prompt of `sometext^> ` but `SET /P "s="sometext^> ""` works...

Comment: Oops: the `>`  is already escaped by the double quotes. Thanks!